# UIWebView: how to hide part of the content of a webpage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

In my app I have a webview that is used solely for displaying the facebook page.
However, the client does not want the top blue bar of facebook to appear; he wants to hide it.
Is there a way to do this?
The bar is 45 pixels, so what I did is I moved the UIWebView in IB in such a way that its top 45 pixels are behind my navigation bar (thus not appearing). 
However, this is not an ideal solution, as the user can see that content when he scrolls up, before bouncing. He can see but not touch it, which will be frustrating for some users.
I tried turning the bouncing off, but then the UI becomes too rigid, and not fluid.
I looked up in Google and Stackoverflow for a couple of hours but didn`t find a solution.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to edit the HTML/CSS of the page itself to hide the HTML elements in question, probably using regular expressions, and feed it into your UIWebView with loadHTMLString:baseURL:.

I've done similar manipulating before and it works, but... it's a different ballgame when the webpages in question don't belong to you. Any time Facebook updates their layout, your app behavior might change until you have time to get an app update approved. Clients want what they want, but make sure your client knows what he's asking for!

Comment: Thanks Janardan! Sorry for the possibly dummy question (I know almost nothing of HTML/CSS), but how can I edit the HTML/CSS of Facebook site? I obviously cannot edit the HTML of their site itself, so I suppose I`d have to do this editing when loading that page on my UIWebView. If that is the case, which method or property (in the iOS SDK) should I use for that?

Comment: Is there a legal issue with blocking sections of other people's websites?

Comment: That would be a great question to ask your lawyer. :) Minimally speaking, Readability and similar services seem to enjoy continued existence.

Answer (score 0):

First test out the javascript code used to hide whatever elements in the webpage and then pass up to `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` of `UIWebView` to run it.